# how to execute a part of code multiple times based on user input

Tags: list, if-statement, random, user-input

I need to create a password creator that can create up to 36 random passwords if needed, all of which are pulled from three different lists that I have made.

I am currently fairly new to python as I am required to learn it due to an upcoming task at my work.

The task in question is to be able to create a password creator of sorts.

So far I have made fairly okay progress, however I'm wanting to know how I can make it so the user can decide how many passwords to create. I have made 3 lists that combine after the user input to create a password of three random words from the said lists.

Sorry if it's really obvious, any help is appreciated!

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import random

colours = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "green", "white", "teal", "gold"]

adjectives = ["fat", "skinny", "long", "short", "hard", "soft", "huge", "small", "wide", "narrow"]

buildings = ["office", "hospital", "church", "apartment", "house", "garage", "shop", "station", "restaurant", "gym"]

print("Password Creator")

amount = raw_input("How many passwords do you need?")            
 if amount == '1':
  print("You chose 1")                                 
                                                      
 elif amount == '2':
  print("You chose 2")
 elif amount == '3':
  print("You chose 3")     #i havent finished this part, just an example of something I thought may work          
 else:
  print("This exceeds the limit! Please enter a value between 1-36.")            


length = int(3)

all = colours + adjectives + buildings
                                            
temp = random.sample(all,length)

password = "".join(temp)

print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the input, convert it to an int, and loop on a `range` of it:

```py
amount = int(raw_input("How many passwords do you need?")

# Common to all passwords, no need to repeat this
length = 3
all = colours + adjectives + buildings

for i in range(amount):
    # Create a password:
    temp = random.sample(all,length)
    password = "".join(temp)
    print(password)
```